# Show that Cauchy Riemann equations hold while f is not differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(z)=f(x+iy)=\sqrt {|xy|}$
a) Show that the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold for (0,0), namely that $f_x(0,0)=-if_y(0,0)$.
b)Show that the derivative of f at z=0 does not exist.

I'm trying to solve it by taking the limits for the partial derivatives of f at 0 while setting the other (constant) variable as 0.
(e.g. $f_x(0,0)=lim_{x\to 0} {{\sqrt {|xy_0|}}-\sqrt {|0y_0|}\over {x-x_0}}$ keeping y=y0 constant at 0 and x0=0)
I think this is the right approach but having trouble with the limits.

edit: Tried another approach without any success:
Writing $|xy|=\sqrt {(xy)^2}$ we get:
$f(x,y)=\sqrt {\sqrt {(xy)^2}}$ so taking the partial derivative of x:
$f_x(x_0,y_0)= $${1}\over {2 \sqrt {\sqrt {(xy)^2}}}$$ {1} \over {\sqrt {(xy)^2}}$$2xy^2$
simplifying: $f_x(x_0,y_0)=$$ xy^2 \over 2|xy|^{2\over 3}$ which is again undefined at (0,0).

Comment: $x_0$ is just $0$ in your limit expression.  This should simplify things enough to see how to proceed.

Comment: yes, but still the limit becomes $0 \over 0$, no idea how to overcome this

Comment: No need to keep $y_0$ constant.  Limit must be the same on every path to $(0,0)$, including paths where $y$ varies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have $f(0+yi)=f(x+0i)=0$ for every $x$ and $y$. Thus the partial derivatives are both zero at the origin, and C-R is trivially satisfied. On the other hand, $$df_{0}=\lim_{|z| \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{|xy|}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}$$
does not exist, because along the line $x=y$, the directional derivative (the limit along that line) is $\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{2}|x|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \ne 0$

**Edit for clarification:**
The reason the partial derivatives are $0$ at the origin, is that in the definition:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x}$$
But the fraction is $0$ for every $x \ne 0$. Therefore, the limit is $0$.

Comment: can you explain why when f(x,0)=f(0,y)=0 for every x,y respectvely, the partial derivatives are 0?

Comment: ok, got it now, when you compute the partial derivative to x you set y=0 so f(x,y)=0 and vice versa

Comment: @ManoPlizzi I've added a little explanation just in case :)

Comment: @Daniel sir, what if for some function $\frac{∂f}{∂x}(z_0)$ and $\frac{∂f}{∂y}(z_0)$ does not exists? then what to say? Cauchy Riemann equations are satisfied or Not? Please help me sir...(I have function defined as $\frac{\bar{z}^{2}}{z^2}$ when $z≠0$ and $0$ when  $z=0$) please help me sir. Please reply

Comment: @akash If the partial derivatives do not exist then it does not make sense to ask whether they satisfy some equations! In any case a necessary condition for being complex differentiable is being $\mathbb{R}^2$-differentiable, which implies that the partial derivatives must exist. So your function is certainly not $\mathbb {C} $-differentiable, no matter what you interpret the CR equations as saying.